# Splitting display among computers

Tags: xorg, x11, remote, multi-monitor, display

If i have 17 system units (computers with monitors) that connected using network, is it possible to display image or video splitted into those computers without having split it manually?

```
1 2 3 4 --> slave PCs
5 6 7 8 
9 A B C
D E F G
| | | |
[switch] 
|
0 --> master PC
```

what is the software to display images and videos into those monitors?

Answer (score 2):

Distributed Multihead X - provided via the Xdmx server from the xorg-server package (or whatever your distro calls it).

- [Xdmx page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdmx)
- [Original DMX project page on SourceForge](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) (from before it merged into X.Org)